# How to link "Searchbar" to Search view Django

Tags: python, html, django

I create a `post_search`view :

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    query = None
    results = []
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            query = form.cleaned_data['query']
            search_vector = SearchVector('title', 'body')
            search_query = SearchQuery(query)
            results = Post.published.annotate(
                search=search_vector,
                rank=SearchRank(search_vector, search_query),
            ).filter(search=search_query).order_by('-rank')

    context = {'form': form, 'query': query, 'results': results}
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', context)
```

And i want to link that to my base.html where i have located an html code for the searchbar (look in the bottom of the file):

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'blog:post_list' %}">
        My Blog</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item mr-2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                </li>
```

Also, now i have a search.html file to make the searchs, idk if i should delete it :

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
 {% if query %}
  <h1>Posts containing "{{ query }}"</h1>
  <h3>
      {% with results.count as total_results %}
        Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize }}
      {% endwith %}
  </h3>
  {% for post in results %}
    <h4><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
    {{ post.body|safe|truncatewords_html:5 }}
  {% empty %}
    <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
  {% endfor %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'blog:search' %}">Search again</a></p>
  {% else %}
    <h1>Search for posts</h1>
    <form method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `<form method="get" action="{% url 'name-of-search-path' %}">`, with `name-of-search-path` the `name=...` in the `path(..)` that triggers the `post_search` view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `<input>` in a form tag with the correct action, and make sure the form field has a correct `name` (`"query"` in your case), á la

```
<form method="get" action="{% url "blog:search" %}">
  <input name="query" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
</form>
```

You do need that template to show the results, don't get rid of it.

Comment: hmm yes i did that, but when i type a search and press enter, i get redirected to the search.html and it shows me ```Search for posts``` and below displays the input to submit the ```Query:```, so its not making a search

Comment: basically displays the ```form below the search.html```

Comment: Oop, I forgot the `name="query"` from the input (it was there in the answer prose though) :) Try the edit...

Comment: maybe i should add all the ```search.html``` template to the ```base.html```, or something like that so when i hit enter on the bar it redirects me with the results.

Comment: No, having a separate search results template is fine. It's the form tag wrapped around the input that has the browser submit your query to the view that does the search and eventually renders the template.

Comment: name="query" Now it works NICE!, thanks, can u explain me something, this name="query" is related to my view? or its an html thing?

Comment: Bit of both. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname - for forms that are submitted with `method="get"` (or where you see `?query=...` in the URL bar), you end up with `request.GET['query']` with `name="query"`. For `method="post"`, you end up with `request.POST['query']` (and POST parameters don't show up in the URL bar).